# Wondering about Context in MVC3 / EF1 CodeFirst Web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, datacontext

I created a simple CodeFirst (Entity Framework 4.1) context and then, using the right mouse button on the controller folder said : "Add Controller", "Entity Framework", picked one of my simple codefirst entities I created and the associated context.  The controller code it genreated is as follows below.

What has me confused is why the Context is created as a private object in the Controller class. I would think that it should be create in a using() so that at the end of the method it could be disposed properly.

What am I missing here?  I'm sure the guys who wrote this no what they are doing.

Thanks

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{ 
    public class TaskInfoController : Controller
    {
        private TaskContext db = new TaskContext();

        //
        // GET: /TaskInfo/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var taskinfos = db.TaskInfos.Include(t => t.TaskGroup);
            return View(taskinfos.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this allows for atomic commits, but I agree, this is not the proper way. I use the Repository/Service/UnitOfWork pattern with MVC3 and EF and it works great. Search SO for it, there is a ton of info on it. In the meantime, move it into a using statement inside the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that contexts should be disposed. Any `IDisposable` should be disposed.

`Controller` implements `IDisposable` so you *can* just override `Controller.Dispose(bool)` and dispose it there.

However, it's really common to use DI to inject a context instance (or something which wraps one, like a repository) as a constructor parameter. In this case you request-scope the instance using your DI container's features. For an example, read *Dependency Injection in .NET*, by Mark Seeman.